# In Azure, why is an AuthClientId also called an Application Id?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I am finding Application Registrations in Azure very confusing.
In my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50921099/invalid-provider-type-specified-cryptographicexception) AuthClientId and Application Id turned out to be the same thing, so why are two names being used?

What is the logic behind this choice of naming?

[Update]

From Joy's link to the glossary I see

**application id (client id)**

"The unique identifier Azure AD issues to an application registration that identifies a specific application and the associated configurations. This application id (client id) is used when performing authentication requests and is provided to the authentication libraries in development time."

I see that Client Id links to a page at [ietf.org](http://ietf.org/)
Which states

"2.2.  Client Identifier

The authorization server issues the registered client a client
identifier -- a unique string representing the registration
information provided by the client."

I guess the metaphor is all about the supplier,customer,product relationship
Where the supplier is Active Directory, the product is authentication and the customer is an application registration.

It is the concept of an "application registration" as a customer that I am having trouble getting used to.  I seek help understanding the choice of words.

The idea of a multi-tenant application does not really work with the "client" metaphor.

[Update]
This [link is the most helpful yet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1) and the most authoritative
Copying from the link

> > 1.1.  Roles
>
> OAuth defines four roles:
>
> resource owner
> An entity capable of granting access to a protected resource.
> When the resource owner is a person, it is referred to as an
> end-user.
>
> resource server
> The server hosting the protected resources, capable of accepting
> and responding to protected resource requests using access tokens.
>
> client
> An application making protected resource requests on behalf of the
> resource owner and with its authorization.  The term "client" does
> not imply any particular implementation characteristics (e.g.,
> whether the application executes on a server, a desktop, or other
> devices).
>
> authorization server
> The server issuing access tokens to the client after successfully
> authenticating the resource owner and obtaining authorization.
>
> The interaction between the authorization server and resource
> server    is beyond the scope of this specification.  The
> authorization server    may be the same server as the resource server
> or a separate entity.    A single authorization server may issue
> access tokens accepted by    multiple resource servers.

However it is still confusing.

"An application making protected resource requests on behalf of the resource owner and with its authorization "

What does it mean by "making a protected resource request on behalf of the resource owner"?

[Update]

After studying Wayne Yang's answer I found this picture at [Slack's oauth page](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth)
[image: OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant flow]

Comment: A web application is a confidential client running on a webserver. You could refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-dev-glossary#application-id-client-id) and [client id](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#page-15).

Comment: Thanks @JoyWang I updated the question.

Comment: Checking this out https://dev.to/rmorschel/oauth-for-dummies

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why is an AuthClientId also called an Application Id?

`Client Id` is the standard definition in [OAuth2.0 protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1). It's actual application too. `Application Id` is just another name in Azure Portal.

This name is more nearly to the application meaning itself. E.g Native Client can be called with the client, but a Web App/Api is actually a server service which runs in a server. But they are all applications.

So Application id is better to make sense for common users. But `client Id` is a standard definition which you cannot change it.

> What does it mean by "making a protected resource request on behalf of
> the resource owner"?

**It means that the client can on behalf of users to request an access token and send the access token to the Resource. (If you let users do this by themselves, it's unsafe and complex)**

In OAuth2.0 framework, **the client is the bridge for Users(Resource Owner), the App (protected resource) and the Identity provider(Authorization server).**  If a user wants to access to the SaaS app, he will send an authorization request to the client, not the Authorization Server directly. Then the client can on behalf of the user to request an access token from the Authorization server and send access token to the App.

Here is the protocol flow:

```
 +--------+                               +---------------+
 |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ->|   Resource    |
 |        |                               |     Owner     |
 |        |<-(B)-- Authorization Grant ---|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(C)-- Authorization Grant -->| Authorization |
 | Client |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(D)----- Access Token -------|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(E)----- Access Token ------>|    Resource   |
 |        |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(F)--- Protected Resource ---|               |
 +--------+                               +---------------+
```

From `C` to `F`, Client is on behalf of the resource owner to obtain an access token and send access token.

For AAD, there is a document for [Authorize access to Azure Active Directory web applications using the OAuth 2.0 code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code):

[image]

Client: Native App

Resource: Web API

Resource Owner: the User

Authorization Server: AAD

Here the Native app is the client which on behalf of the user to request token and send the token to the resource.

Comment: Thank you, but I am having a hard time understanding that all the users are the resource owner.

Comment: Hi @KirstenGreed . Not All users are the resource owner. If you want to restrict user assignment, you can go to AAD> Enterprise application > Select your app > User assignment required> Set to Yes> Add Users in Users and groups under this application.

Comment: A user as a resource owner is also counter intuitive.... but I guess that is a different question.

Comment: Oh wait, looking at https://dev.to/rmorschel/oauth-for-dummies  are the facebook accounts etc the resource?

Comment: Hi @KirstenGreed , Not really. Facebook and Google+ accounts are just Identity provider credentials.  The resource should be some App or API resources.

Comment: @KirstenGreed , Also, strictly speaking, resource owner is the owner of the app. If you want to use Resource owner password credentials flow, you can add the user to the owner of the application in the application registration/enterprise application in AAD. But widely speaking, users who can access the app are all resource owners if there are not other roles for this app.

Comment: I asked about it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148139/in-oauth2-where-are-the-resources-that-the-resource-owner-owns

Comment: Are you going to update the information about the resources ?

Comment: Hi @KirstenGreed . This question is different from the OpenID connect one. I think this answer can give a correct response for your question.

Comment: I am finding "(If you let users do this by themselves, it's unsafe and complex)"  confusing because the the users do indeed have safe access to the resource. ( ie Facebook user can access their Facebook Assets)

Comment: @KirstenGreed . That's OpenID connect, NOT Oauth2.0. OAuth2.0 cannot do that. Also, actually, even in OpenID connect, there is also client in the identity provider. OpenID is based on OAuth. For end user, you cannot feel How the backend works. If you use Fiddler to catch the traffic you will find that there should also be a clientid in the http request. Use cannot obtain token and send token direclty.

Comment: Also, this is what and why OAuth2.0 can do.

Answer (score 4):

In Azure, to create a Service Principal you have to **register an Application**. Thats why its called Application Id (AppId).  So:

*AppId = ClientId = AuthClientId = Id of your Application*

and

*TenantId = DirectoryId = Name or Guid of your Azure Active Directory*

Comment: What is a client?

Comment: I don't understand your question. A client is a software (or hardware) that access a remote service.

Comment: so it does not make sense for a client to also be called an application but that is what your answer implies. I updated the question to show that I am trying to understand the thinking behind these name choices.

Comment: Hi @KirstenGreed , Client Id is the standard definition in [OAuth2.0 protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.1).It's actually application too. Application Id is just another name in Azure Portal. This name is more nearly to the application meaning itself. E.g Native Client can be called with the client, but a web app/api is actually a server service which runs in a server. But they are all applications. So Application id is better to make sense for common users. But client Id is a standard definition which you cannot change it.

Comment: Thank you @WayneYang-MSFT , the link you give has the answer.   I updated the question to show that even with the link I still find the answer confusing