# How to use dotnet?

Tags: linux, .net-core

I'm trying to compile an old VS2010 Framework 4.0 project with dotnet command for Linux and I provided a source path to a .sln file but I'm keep getting MSB1003 error.

Do I need to import the project to VS2019?

VS2019 opens and compile from the GUI without problem, but for Windows x86 platform.

I want to run my App in Ubuntu and CentOS 6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393395/msbuild-error-msb1003-specify-a-project-or-solution-file)

Comment: Try the following it seems similar to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393395/msbuild-error-msb1003-specify-a-project-or-solution-file

Comment: @Alejandro It seems like only works with C# projects. I guess I must to turn my project in to a C# project. I wonder how now.

Comment: @confused It seems like only works with C# projects. I guess I must to turn my project in to a C# project. I wonder how now.

Comment: What kind of project do you have right now?

Comment: @Alejandro Is an App that get some data from a MySQL server, format that data and send it to a webapp in a SOAP envelope. It mostly work without user interference.

Comment: @E_Blue So it's a console program?

Comment: @Alejandro No, it have a GUI to show the log in RTF format and a child window to configure the MySQL server, and the webapp login data.

Comment: @E_Blue So it's a Winforms or WPF program?

Comment: @Alejandro A WinForm

Comment: @E_Blue Then you cannot run on Linux at all. .NET Core doesn't supoprt neither Winforms nor WPF on non-Windows OSs. You could, at most, run console programs or web pages. An alternative is to continue to use the normal .NET Framework and run it with Mono or even Wine. Or, turn it into a console program and make a native Linux GUI.

Comment: @Alejandro Does Mono IDE have a GUI in Windows? I just downloaded and both, x86 and x64 versions run in console.

Comment: @E_Blue Mono is just a runtime, not an IDE. It runs .NET binaries on Linux.

Comment: @Alejandro Ok. I was thinking in MonoDevelop that I used some time ago in Linux.